# ASP.NET MVC how to send param from @Ajax.ActionLink to method in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)Model[i]["name"], "Info", "Home", new { uid = Model[i]["uid"].ToString() }, null)  

[HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Info(string uid)
            {
                TempData["uid"] = uid;
                SearchModel model = new SearchModel();
                List<DataTable> tables = model.GetUserInfo(uid);
                TempData["tables"] = tables;

                return View(model);
            }
```

In the controller, there is a method that returns JsonResult. This method is used to obtain data, on the basis of which the js code will be executed.

```
public JsonResult GetCountryRisk(SearchModel model)
    {
        string uid = TempData["uid"].ToString();
        IEnumerable<CountryRisk> list = new List<CountryRisk>();
        list = model.GetCountryRisk(uid);
        TempData["uid"] = uid;
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The view has elements that simulate tabs and when clicked on the selected item, Ajax is called, which receives the data and passes it to the script.

```
    <div id="tabHeadDiv">
        <input type="button" value="Summary" class="tabControl" id="1" onclick="ShowOrHideTabs(this.id)" />
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Relations", "Info", null, new AjaxOptions { Url = Url.Action("GetDataForGraph"), OnSuccess = "DrawGraph" }, new { @id = "2", @class = "tabControl" })
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Map", "Info", null, new AjaxOptions { Url = Url.Action("GetCountryRisk"), OnSuccess = "drawRegionsMap" }, new { @id = "3", @class = "tabControl" })
    </div>
```

Problem is that if a user opens several links in a new tab and wants to go to the tab, then on all tabs the result will be displayed, which was executed last. 
So I want to understand if it's possible to send parameter to the GetCountryRisk method without using `TempData ["uid"]`.

Comment: Make `uid` a part of the search model and pass it as a param in links

Comment: @Andrei Could you explain it little more? As I understood, I need to pass it in routeValues? I tried to do like             `@Ajax.ActionLink("Map", "Info", new { tUid = ViewBag.Main.Rows[0]["uid"]}, new AjaxOptions { Url = Url.Action("GetCountryRisk"), OnSuccess = "drawRegionsMap" }, new { @id = "3", @class = "tabControl" })` but in controllers it return `null`.

Comment: Expanded in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, stop using a ViewBag or a TempData for `uid`. This is clearly a part of your state, and while these key-value stores have their uses, they are no good for your case.

Make `uid` a part of `SearchModel`, as it is obviously important for you as you handle search requests, and in `Info` action do this:

```
SearchModel model = new SearchModel();
model.UID = uid;
```

Now on the page I don't really understand why the Ajax.ActionLink mentions one controller/action pair and then uses another as the URL. Here is how I would imagine it:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Your controller name",
    "GetCountryRisk",
    new {uid = Model.UID},
    new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "drawRegionsMap" },
    new { @id = "3", @class = "tabControl" })
```

Finally in the GetCountryRisk action just use uid:

```
public JsonResult GetCountryRisk(SearchModel model)
{
    string uid = model.UID;
```

Comment: Thanks, that problem solved. I accept your answer as solution. But could you then explain how I can whithout TempData cache data which i get from first completing that Json? Because of user can swith from "tabs" and each time method would genereate Json again.

Comment: @IhorMykytiv, that depends. TempData is not a proper way to keep bulky stuff cached anyways. If it does not take a huge amount of time to generate the JSON, I see no problem creating it all over again for each request.

Comment: Problem is that user may switch tabs as many time as he want. Second things that method may return big amount of data from db (for example it may executing up for 5-10 seconds) and if user each time will wait, it would be not well. So I need find way to evaid that time. Anyway thanks you for your patience :)